# Publishing to Azure Function from VS2022 failing without apparent reason

Tags: azure-functions, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

When trying to publish to an Azure function through Visual Studio 2022, I keep getting this, regardless of what I've tried:

[image]

Here's what I've done:

1. Tried to publish from imported publish profile.
2. Tried to publish directly to the resource group / function app
3. Checked my Azure credentials in VS
4. Deleted function app and started a new one
5. Started a new project in VS
6. 4 and 5 simultaneously
7. Checked VS for updates/missing files

I'm trying to deploy to a function app that's set to .NET 6, Consumption (serverless), on Linux. The "output log" and tmp file say nothing that helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

had this issue with an older version of VS 2022. Updating to the latest versions seemed to resolved.
Also - check you're signed into your Microsoft account correctly.
If you click the account logo top right in VS 2022, make sure there are no prompts to re-enter credentials or similar.

So:

1. Make sure your VS 2022 is updated and
2. Make sure you're signed in properly
3. if you've recently made any account changes - try restarting all VS 2022 instances.

Comment: Sign out and sign back in again in VS2022 solved this for me many times.